Thread pool sizing in Java, say JDK17
Not a specific question as such, so understand any down votes or negative reaction.
I recently joined a team with an existing codebase which segregates the I/O operations into categories each having it's own thread executor e.g. one for JDBC operations and another for REST calls into which CompletableFutures are submitted. This kind of makes sense and cleanly separates the I/O responsibilities I guess.
However it's the size of the thread pools which caused me to raise an eyebrow. For instance the JDBC pool is an executor with 50 threads. When I questioned this and pointed out the idiomatic sizing guidelines provided by Goetz for CPU (#processors + 1) and I/O bound operations, I was told not to worry. They are just "soft threads".
The JDK is pre-21, therefore virtual threads are not in the picture.
Am I being spun a line of nonsense here ?

what do they mean by "soft threads"?  also, does your jdbc connection pool allow 50 connections?  i would expect jdbc operations to be io bound, and therefore having a larger thread pool seems reasonable (assuming you have the number of connections to support it)

Note to readers: Virtual threads would definitely change the calculus here.

@BasilBourque Does it? VThreads 'change the calculus' from "this system is going to end up running 20k concurrent threads, that's got some fairly severe issues, you need way better stack size management at the very least" to "oh, yeah, wahtever, VThreads, no problem" (which is rather oversimplifying matters). It doesn't meaningfully change the calculus when we're talking about 500 threads. Worrying about 500 actual full blown threads is premature optimizing, and I say that with all derision that is inherent in that choice of words.

@rzwitserloot I disagree. Several hundred threads on a machine of about 8-24 cores, if busy with tasks that involve much blocking such as the JDBC & REST calls described here, are good candidates for virtual threads. At best we would see better overall throughput with CPUs pushed closer to 100% utilization, and at worst we would see about the same performance as the platform threads currently used. Especially on Java 24+ where the synchronized pinning goes away. On a client making few calls, not so (we would agree), but on a busy server, yes (we disagree).

I would love to see some realistic stack that switches to vthreads and then shows serious performance improvements. I'm sure it's possible, just, usually with some basic reasoning I end up at: ... yah and there it sort of wouldn't matter / a very minor rewrite would get you all the performance benefits vthreads could possibly give you, such as introducing a max-100-simultaneous latch or whatnot.

It just doesn't matter. For all the FUD about having loads of threads, the 'cost' of a single thread is infinitesemal.
The cost of a 'context switch' is also small; let's get a sense of perspective here, writing a software stack that hops from thread to thread 100 times a second is no problem, CPUs are a lot more capable than these fear stories insinuate. Also, context switches are fundamental - a large part of the cost is paid by clearing out CPU cache pages and loading in new context, which you have to do regardless of threading model - if it's all a bunch of pooled NIO-optimized async wundercode, it... still context switches just as much if not more. cache pages are small, and trying to serve 1000 incoming requests at the same time means you'll be invalidating those cache pages a lot no matter how you care to solve the problem!
There are a few places where you run into actual trouble, and these problems are solved by pools. The trouble that the pools solve occurs when you have thousands of threads; hence, having ~50 threads per 'concern', with 10 concerns, for a total of 500 threads, is not a problem whatsoever.
The problems that thousands of threads cause:

If 1000 connections come in all at the same time, your system will now attempt to serve all 1000 jobs roughly simultaneously. If the job at hand fundamentally just takes 20ms to complete no matter how many threads or optimized code paths you care to throw at it, then it's going to have to take 20,000ms (20 entire seconds) to get through all 1000 jobs. In this setup even if 100% optimal, each job will take 20s to complete. However, there is some number such that trying to parallelize more than that amount of jobs does not meaningfully improve performance (in fact, likely, decreases it). Let's say it's 10. Then it'd be better to pick up 10 out of the incoming 10k jobs, deal with them all and deliver (those people got a near instant response: 200ms), then another 10 (400ms), then another, and so on.

Overload. If the requests are endless, and come in faster than they can be processed, eventually some system somewhere needs to start hanging up, because not doing that means your machine will just crash completely (Out of memory errors because the amount of open jobs just keeps growing forever). A thread pool system makes that easy: You have a queue of things left to do, that queue has a hard limit above which the inflow system just starts hanging up in requestors immediately, and the thread pool just goes through em top to bottom.

stack sizes. Each thread gets a stack and the RAM for those starts adding up. That's RAM not usable by heap and such. If each thread has 1MB worth of stack (that's relatively little, even!) and you have 1000 threads, 1GB of RAM is gone just for stacks alone. You can easily make a system that runs 5000 threads simultaneously, but that does mean using the custom Thread constructor to pick a stack size, make it very small, but now your code needs to be written to deal with that; if you ever get one of those stack traces that has 140 lines in it, that's probably not going to work on a small stack. It's a complication that you can solve by limiting the total # of threads. With 500 threads in the system each having 1MB stacks that's 'just' half a gigabyte worth, that is managable; in contrast to have 5000 threads total where it is not.


All of those problems simply do not occur if you have a small constant x multiple threads vs cores. So, 8 cores, 40 threads? No problem. 8 cores, 4000 threads? That might not be such a good idea unless you really know what you are doing.
Looking at it from the other side, if you have 8 cores, and 10 threads for those cores, and 5 of the threads are 'stuck' waiting for something, that is bad - now your CPUs are idling. The java library ecosystem, including most of the java.* classes themselves, do not really document how and when they freeze a thread, let alone make it possible to use automated source introspection tools to know. And in a certain way, they all do - any time code attempts to run code in a class that has never been loaded yet, the classloader system runs in that thread and accesses disk which therefore means the CPU falls asleep! In practice this cost is amortized and goes away a few seconds after boot, but, theoretically speaking...
Making that 50 threads reduces the odds significantly.
It's hard to know: How do you test that your CPUs are idling? Are you in the habit of writing unit tests that set up a full system and then fake a flood of simultaneous requests, then check how fast the system plows through it, how it deals with a sustained stream of requests coming in faster than can be handled? Because you should really have that if you decide to try to 'optimize' by running only as many threads as you have cores, or apply the Goetz rule.
NB: However, for different reasons, that setup seems highly suspect to me. It is much more difficult to write and reason about code that has to 'farm out' any DB interaction that it does to a separate pool, it gets you into a java version of callback hell. You should have e.g. one thread per incoming request, and a pool of JDBC connection objects. Not '50 threads for JDBC queries, 50 threads for reading files, 50 threads for calculating order lists, 50 threads for processing HTTP headers' and so on.

All good points, and wise. I would add a not-so-minor note: The stacks on platforms threads as implemented on common OSes allocate more memory as needed, but do not give back that memory. They grow, but do not shrink. Your example of 500 threads with 1 MB stack each, in total taking  "'just' half a gigabyte" is true… until those stacks grow. If those threads ever grow to 10 MB at any point in the past, now we have 5 gigs of memory. In contrast, the stacks on virtual threads grow and shrink as needed. So in that same example, virtual threads would never in total be using 5 gigs.

can't believe someone have finally written that. tomcat 4, which was released in 2002, had default thread pool capacity of 50/200 spare/max threads: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/coyote.html, what have been changed in Java 21 that we have started worrying about 50 threads in 2024?

@AndreyB.Panfilov the problem is that the OP vaguely refers to the “idiomatic sizing guidelines provided by Goetz” but does not tell what number of threads have been derived from the guideline, not to speak of showing the actual calculation. It seems like the OP ended up at a lower number, but what number, 49, maybe? Who knows. Then, the response from the other team members, “They are just ‘soft threads’ ” isn’t helpful either…
